TypeError: Cannot create property '375' on number '1'
I'm trying to create an algorithm visualiser for heap sort. In order to keep track of the swaps that happen during the heap sort execution, I created an animations array that will include the indexes of each swap. The heap sort animation works fine, but once I introduce the animations array into my code, I run into this error. TypeError: Cannot create property '375' on number '1'
Sort.js
heapSortVisualiser() {
    const animations = heapSort(this.state.array);
    console.log(animations);
}

HeapSort.js
// i is an index in arr, N is size of heap
function heapify(arr, N, i, animations) {
    let largest = i; // initialise largest as root
    let l = 2 * i + 1; // left = 2i + 1
    let r = 2 * i + 2; // right = 2i + 2

    // If left child is larger than root
    if (l < N && arr[l] > arr[largest]) { largest = l; }

    // If right child is larger than current largest
    if (r < N && arr[r] > arr[largest]) { largest = r; }

    // If largest is no longer the root
    if (largest !== i) {
        animations.push({
            type: 'heapify',
            index1: i,
            index2: largest
        })
        [arr[i], arr[largest]] = [arr[largest], arr[i]]; // swap i and largest

        // Recursively heapify the affected subtree
        heapify(arr, N, largest);
    }
}

export function heapSort(arr, animations = []) {
    let N = arr.length;

    // Build heap (rearrange array)
    for (let i = Math.floor(N / 2) - 1; i >= 0; i--) { heapify(arr, N, i, animations) };

    // Extract top element of heap one by one until heap is empty
    for (let i = N - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        animations.push({
            type: 'sort',
            index1: i,
            index2: 0
        })
        [arr[i], arr[0]] = [arr[0], arr[i]] // move current root to end

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap
        heapify(arr, i, 0, animations);
    }
    return animations;
}

Initially I thought the problem was pushing a JavaScript object to the array was the issue, so I used JSON.stringify()  to convert the object to a string but the same error persists.

Can you share the sample data that has been used to test this code?

I am using a function to create an array of random integers, which gets passed to my heapSort function.
[247, 98, 74, 10, 33, 137, 375]

The error TypeError: Cannot create property '375' on number '1' suggests that somewhere in your code, you're attempting to add a property to a number, which is not allowed in JavaScript.
If you rewrite this function to TypeScript, it should be easier to spot a mistake.

But here's my guess:
You call the heapify(arr, N, largest); function without animations once (an other times with animations).
Trying to .push on an array which has not been passed might cause this error.

Hi thanks for the suggestion. I noticed I did not pass animations into my heapify(arr, N, largest) function at one point in my code. It still shows the same issue even after that fix, so I will try rewriting as TypeScript as you've mentioned and see if I get better results from there.

Update:
I can get the animations array now. It was a semi-colon issue...


// i is an index in arr, N is size of heap
function heapify(arr, N, i, animations) {
    let largest = i; // initialise largest as root
    let l = 2 * i + 1; // left = 2i + 1
    let r = 2 * i + 2; // right = 2i + 2

    // If left child is larger than root
    if (l < N && arr[l] > arr[largest]) { largest = l; }

    // If right child is larger than current largest
    if (r < N && arr[r] > arr[largest]) { largest = r; }

    // If largest is no longer the root
    if (largest !== i) {
        animations.push({
            type: 'heapify',
            indexA: i,
            indexB: largest
        }); // ADDED SEMICOLON HERE
        [arr[i], arr[largest]] = [arr[largest], arr[i]]; // swap i and largest

        // Recursively heapify the affected subtree
        heapify(arr, N, largest, animations);
    }
}

export function heapSort(arr, animations = []) {
    let N = arr.length;

    // Build heap (rearrange array)
    for (let i = Math.floor(N / 2) - 1; i >= 0; i--) { heapify(arr, N, i, animations) };

    // Extract top element of heap one by one until heap is empty
    for (let i = N - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        animations.push({
            type: 'sort',
            indexA: i,
            indexB: 0
        }); // ADDED SEMICOLON HERE
        [arr[i], arr[0]] = [arr[0], arr[i]] // move current root to end

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap
        heapify(arr, i, 0, animations);
    }
    return animations
}



Thanks to all who provided their time to help me with the issue. Was not expecting my error to be because of something so trivial
